# A blank card when put inside modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using this code : http://codepen.io/andytran/pen/xweoPN/ to create an information card slider but i think the code `<div class="card">` is having some problems when put in a modal.

I've created a pen with my current code, Kindly review it and suggest the changes to remove that blank card while clicking on the modal. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWmYxN

In the first card a blank card with the text how it works is present, how to remove that blank card?

Comment: There are 2 codepen, which one has problem? I tried the second one and it seems it works pretty well.

Comment: the second one has a problem. Observe the difference, when you press the modal button, a blank card appears and when you click next the real content appears which is not the case with the first , original one @shaochuancs

Comment: Do you mean you don't want "How it works" text, and when the modal is popped up, you want the picture to display immediately?

Comment: I don't want the blank modal which appears. --> http://prntscr.com/f9kam6, I don't want that to appear, when I click modal button, it should open the first card with the data and not the blank one @shaochuancs

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite familiar with the libraries that you used here. But anyway, something like this can fix your issue if nothing else works out.

```
$("#modalBtn").click(function() {
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      $("#next").click();
    }, 250
  );
});
```

EDIT:
 Sorry about that, I forgot that you should add an ID to your button that calls the modal.

```
<button id="modalBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work out. this crippled my next button.

Comment: @NinjaBoy, Sorry about that, I modified the code. Have a look.

Comment: Works but distorts the UI, anyways thanks. Giving a heads up since it worked somehow. Can you check the code once and see what's the reason for that problem as it comes only if I put modal. maybe there are some html errors which might miss, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to put this code only in $(document).ready

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
   $('#myModal.products').height(283);
   },200);
```

so your jquery code will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   window.setTimeout(function() {
   $('#myModal.products').height(283);
   },200);
          var getProductHeight =   $('.product.active').height();

  $('.products').css({
    height: getProductHeight
  });


  function calcProductHeight() {
    getProductHeight = $('.product.active').height();

    $('.products').css({
      height: getProductHeight
    });
  }

  function animateContentColor() {
    var getProductColor = $('.product.active').attr('product-color');

    $('body').css({
      background: getProductColor
    });

    $('.title').css({
      color: getProductColor
    });

    $('.btn').css({
      color: getProductColor
    });
  }

  var productItem = $('.product'),
    productCurrentItem = productItem.filter('.active');

  $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nextItem = productCurrentItem.next();

    productCurrentItem.removeClass('active');

    if (nextItem.length) {

      productCurrentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
    } else {
      productCurrentItem = productItem.first().addClass('active');
    }

    calcProductHeight();
    animateContentColor();
  });

  $('#prev').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var prevItem = productCurrentItem.prev();

    productCurrentItem.removeClass('active');

    if (prevItem.length) {
      productCurrentItem = prevItem.addClass('active');
    } else {
      productCurrentItem = productItem.last().addClass('active');
    }

    calcProductHeight();
    animateContentColor();
  });

  // Ripple
  $('[ripple]').on('click', function(e) {
    var rippleDiv = $('<div class="ripple" />'),
      rippleSize = 60,
      rippleOffset = $(this).offset(),
      rippleY = e.pageY - rippleOffset.top,
      rippleX = e.pageX - rippleOffset.left,
      ripple = $('.ripple');

    rippleDiv.css({
      top: rippleY - (rippleSize / 2),
      left: rippleX - (rippleSize / 2),
      background: $(this).attr("ripple-color")
    }).appendTo($(this));

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      rippleDiv.remove();
    }, 1900);
  });
});
```

Thats it

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. I forgot to add "active class", see the codepen for the updated code :D Thanks for the time.

Comment: plus 1 for the time taken to help. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I forgot assigning the active class to the product class

```
<div class="product-active">
```

this will make the first screen to appear and if there's no active class, then it'll show a blank screen since it doesn't know what to show. A small typo got me on feet. Anyways, this is for the future reference if anyone makes a silly mistake like this.

Thanks.